# copy tr table to another table tr and reversely

Tags: jquery, html

I can copy rows from table 1 to table 2 after clicking on a checkbox **(copy-one)** of row in table 1, there is one checkbox **(copy-all)** as well in the the thead tag that allow to copy all rows of table 1 to table 2. Now I would like to make the reverse : Copy the rows from table 1 that are in table 2 back to table 1 after click on **(copy-one)** or **(copy-all)**.

Here are the codes that copy each row from table 1 to table 2.

1- table 1

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="table1">
 <thead>
<tr>
<th>Fecha</th>
<th>Paciente</th>
<th>Cedula</th>
<th><input type="checkbox" id="copy-all" /></th>
</tr>
</thead>
 <tbody id="copy-all-rows">
<?php

foreach($display_billings as $fac)

{
?>
<tr>
<td><?=$fecha1;?></td>
<td ><?=$paciente['nombre'];?></td>
<td ><?=$paciente['cedula'];?></td>
<td><input type="checkbox"  class="copy-one"  /></td>
</tr>  

<?php
}

?>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

2- table2

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered"  id="table2" >
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Fecha</th>
<th>Paciente</th>
<th>Cedula</th>
<th><input type="checkbox" id="copy-all" /></th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

</tbody>
</table>
```

3- JQUERY

```
jQuery('.copy-one').on('click', function(e) {
if($(this).is(':checked',true)) {
$(this).closest('tr').fadeOut(800, function(){ 
$(this).remove();
});
$(this).closest('tr').clone().appendTo('#table2>tbody');
}
})
```

Here are the codes that copy all rows from table 1 to table 2.

```
jQuery('#copy-all').on('click', function(e) {
if($(this).is(':checked',true)) {
$("#copy-all-rows").fadeOut(800, function(){ 
$(this).remove();
});
$("#copy-all-rows").clone().appendTo('#table2');
}
})
```

How can i make the reverse ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

1. Select row for cloning and append to table2
2. Remove row from table1

Comment: hello, you can write and i will try to undersdand you. I really need help !

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow. You could try adding some code to your answer to give an example of how you can achieve that.